# Why does java.nio.file.DirectoryStream use unbounded generics?

Tags: java, generics

The only usage of `DirectoryStream` that I have seen uses the type `Path` as its type parameter, `DirectoryStream<Path>` which comes from `Files.newDirectoryStream(Path)`.

Additionally, I don't understand why it allows for any type because of the following statement in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html):

> If hasNext method returns true, and is followed by a call to the next method, it is guaranteed that the next method will not throw an exception due to an I/O error, or because the stream has been closed.

This must mean it checks whether the `Path` is accessible beforehand and therefore cannot be a generic type.

Comment: Does anybody know why this question was down voted and how it could be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does `java.nio.file.DirectoryStream` use unbounded generics?
>
> The only usage of `DirectoryStream` that I have seen uses the type `Path` as its type parameter, `DirectoryStream<Path>` which comes from `Files.newDirectoryStream(Path)`.

If you look at `SecureDirectoryStream`, that interface extends `DirectoryStream` with an unbounded generic.  However, the only concrete implementation of `SecureDirectoryStream` is also parameterized with `Path`.

So, the most plausible explanations are:

- the parameterization is to enable possible future enhancement, or
- there was originally an intention to provide directory streams of `File`, but it was abandoned ... too late to get rid of the parameter entirely.

Either way, the parameter is a harmless anomaly, at the moment.

> This must mean it checks whether the Path is accessible beforehand and therefore cannot be a generic type.

The parameter is presumably unbounded because there is no suitable common super-interface for `Path` and `File`.  The fact that it can't *really* be any type is ... unfortunate, but by no means unique.  There are other cases where there are implied type requirements are not expressed in the static typing.  For example:

- The `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object)` method fails if the object doesn't implement `Serializable`.
- The `Arrays.sort(Object[])` method fails if the array elements don't all implement `Comparable`.

And I expect there are other examples where some parameterizations of a generic class make little sense.

Answer (score 0):

**'This must mean it checks whether the Path is accessible beforehand.'** Yes it does.

`hasNext()` actually fetches the element and returns `false` if that fetched element is `null` else `true`.

So when you call `next()` just after `hasNext()`, it does not put any extra efforts but just returns that fetched( fetched from `hasNext()`) element.

Answer (score 0):

The system is buffering the next element.  This from the Javadocs:

> Due to read-ahead, the Iterator may return one or more elements after the directory stream has been closed. Once these buffered elements have been read, then subsequent calls to the hasNext method returns false, and subsequent calls to the next method will throw NoSuchElementException.